# Did I calculate the non-seasonal Mean Absolute Scaled Error (MASE) correctly?

Tags: forecasting, error, mase

This is the formula:

[image: formula]

[Here](https://otexts.com/fpp3/accuracy.html) is the link to page in the book. I am not confident I am interpreting the formula correctly. Below is my data:

[image: data]

I calculate the non-seasonal MASE to be 1.125. Is this correct?

Comment: There are blind or visually impaired users of this site who read it with screen readers. Those screen readers can't handle images of formulas and data. Please edit your question to include a Markdown table of the data and type the formula's LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't.

And I am not even calculating the correct MASE from your data - *because I can't*.

The MASE is calculated by diving your forecast's MAE (which for your "Naive Forecast" column would be 30.17) by the MAE achieved by the random walk forecast *in-sample*. Note that the page you link refers to "the *training* MAE".

And since we don't know the historical time series, we can't compute this scaling factor.

---

As an example, suppose the historical time series you use as training data consists of only three data points 140, 110, 140. Then the in-sample random walk forecast for the last two data points (we can't give a random walk forecast for the very first data point) would be 140, 110. The MAE of this random walk forecast in-sample would be 30. So with your "real" forecast's MAE of 30.17, the MASE would be $\frac{30.17}{30}\approx 1.006$.

As a matter of fact, this kind of confusion about the scaling factor for the MASE happens very often. And to be honest, scaling by the random walk's *out of sample* MAE is quite fine, too - just be careful to note which scaling factor you are using.

Comment: Okay, thank you!